# Chocolatey list without version?

Tags: chocolatey, clist

What is the secret flag to use for listing all Chocolatey install packages WITHOUT version (only package names) ? :)

> choco list -l

Chocolatey v0.10.15
7zip 19.0
androidstudio 3.5.3.0

> choco list -l 'secret flag ?'

Chocolatey
7zip
androidstudio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a secret flag to enable this.

Part of the value of a package manager is to know what package is installed, and also what version of the package is installed.

You could run the command:

```
choco list -l -r
```

Which would output the information in a slightly different format, including a `|` to separate the package name and version, which you could then parse separately and get only the package names.

Answer (score 2):

There is no secret flag - but just because there is an official one (at least since v0.10.6 https://github.com/chocolatey/choco/pull/1254 - see `choco list -?`):

```
 --idonly, --id-only
 Id Only - Only return Package Ids in the list results. Available in 0.1-
   0.6+.
```

I suppose you want that list to install the packages again somewhere else. So I also recommend adding `-r` to "get **r**id" of the additional output (header/footer):

```
-r, --limitoutput, --limit-output
 LimitOutput - Limit the output to essential information
```

The complete command will be `choco list -l -r --id-only`

Answer (score 0):

If you use:

```
choco list -l -r --id-only | ForEach-Object {echo "choco install -y $PSItem"}
```

will give you a list like:

```
choco install -y 7zip
choco install -y 7zip.install
choco install -y adobereader
...
```